# Showing recursive Formula for Polynomial Interpolation

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, lagrange-interpolation

Let $f : [a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Define
$$
f[a_0, ..., a_n] := \frac{f[a_1, ..., a_n]-f[a_0, ..., a_{n-1}]}{a_n - a_0}
$$
with $f[a]=f(a)$. Consider now $(m + 1)$ distinct nodes $x_j \in \mathbb{R}$ for $j \in \{ 0, \ldots, m \}$. Define the polynomial
$$
q_{k+1}(x) = q_k(x) + f[x_0, \ldots, x_{k+1}](x - x_0)(x - x_1)\ldots(x - x_k)
$$
with $q_0(x)=f(x_0)$. I want to show that the Lagrange interpolation polynomial of degree $m$, $p_m(x)$, is in fact given by $p_m(x)=q_m(x)$.

How do you show that something is a Lagrange interpolation polynomial? Do you need to show that you can transform into the familiar form of
$$
p_m(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{m} L_k(x) \cdot y_k
$$
Or, is there any easier method? I have tried induction but I can't unpack the recursive function. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4048158/proof-of-relation-between-divided-difference-and-interpolation-polynomial-coeffi

Comment: I don't really understand the proof because I'm not sure how the conclusion shows that it is a Lagrange interpolating polynomial. In general, how does one show that a polynomial $q_m(x)$ is a Lagrange interpolating polynomial? Is it enough to show that it $q_m(x_i) = f(x_i)$ for all $i$?

Comment: Yes, because we also know that $p_m(x_i) = f(x_i)$ for $i = 0, \dots, m$. If two degree $m$ polynomials coincide at $m + 1$ points, then they must be the same polynomial.

Why? Let $r(x) = p_m(x) - q_m(x)$. Clearly $r(x_i) = 0$, so if $r$ is not the zero polynomial we can factor it into $c\cdot(x - x_0)(x - x_1)\cdots(x-x_m)$. But expanding that would yield a nonzero $x^{m+1}$ term. But since $p_m$ and $q_m$ are only of degree $m$, the degree of $r$ must be at most $m$, so this is a contradiction. Therefore $p_m(x) - q_m(x) = r(x) = 0$, so $p_m = q_m$.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: After going through the proof I don't understand it. Firstly, what is the induction hypothesis? Is it that $L_m(x)$ is the m-th interpolating polynomial? Also are we assuming $k \le m$. Secondly, why is it valid to use the recursive formula with $\psi_m(x)$, which does not include $x - x_0$? Thirdly, where does equation (5) come from? I would ask the person who posted the answer but they have not been active for some time.

Comment: $L_m$ is defined to be the interpolating (Lagrange) polynomial for every number of points. The induction hypothesis appears to be that their equation (2) holds for all values of $m$ less than the value you're considering. I don't see the letter $m$ in their answer. They appear to be using $m$ in the same way you're using $k$. I think they skipped some steps that would become clear if you were to expand the definitions of things and work out the math step-by-step (which I haven't). If you can't answer all your questions, it would be good to write a comment on that question rather than this one.

Comment: I added an alternative proof. The bulk of the work is just trudging through symbolic manipulations to directly show that the leading coefficient of the Lagrange polynomial satisfies the divided difference formula. I definitely wouldn't say it's simpler than the others, but it might be a more intuitive perspective for some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a different approach than the ones in [Proof of relation between divided difference and interpolation polynomial coefficient](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4048158/proof-of-relation-between-divided-difference-and-interpolation-polynomial-coeffi). Possibly unnecessarily complex, but it gets the job done. We will see that the divided difference is the leading coefficient of the Lagrange polynomial, which will let us prove that the two types of polynomials are equal by induction.

Let $\ell[x_0, x_1, \cdots, x_n]$ be the leading coefficient of the Lagrange polynomial which passes through $f$ at $x_0, x_1, \cdots, x_n$. It is easily seen that
$$
\ell[x_0, x_1, \cdots, x_n] = \sum_{i=0}^n f(x_i) \prod_{\substack{j=0\\j\neq i}}^n \frac1{x_i - x_j}.
$$

We will show that $\ell[x_0, \cdots, x_n] = f[x_0, \cdots, x_n]$. Observe that
\begin{align}
& \ell[x_0, \cdots, x_n] - \ell[x_1, \cdots, x_{n+1}]\\
=\,& \sum_{i=0}^n f(x_i) \prod_{\substack{j=0\\j\neq i}}^n \frac1{x_i - x_j} - \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} f(x_i) \prod_{\substack{j=1\\j\neq i}}^{n+1} \frac1{x_i - x_j} \\
=\,& f(x_0)\prod_{\substack{j=1}}^n \frac1{x_0 - x_j} + 
\sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i)
\left(\prod_{\substack{j=0\\j\neq i}}^n \frac1{x_i - x_j} - \prod_{\substack{j=1\\j\neq i}}^{n+1} \frac1{x_i - x_j}\right)
- f(x_{n+1})\prod_{\substack{j=1}}^n \frac1{x_{n+1} - x_j}\\
=\,& f(x_0)\prod_{\substack{j=1}}^n \frac1{x_0 - x_j} + 
\sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i)
\left(\frac1{x_i - x_0} - \frac1{x_i - x_{n+1}}\right)\prod_{\substack{j=1\\j\neq i}}^n \frac1{x_i - x_j}
- f(x_{n+1})\prod_{\substack{j=1}}^n \frac1{x_{n+1} - x_j}\\
=\,& f(x_0)\prod_{\substack{j=1}}^n \frac1{x_0 - x_j} + 
\sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i)
\frac{x_0 - x_{n+1}}{(x_i - x_0)(x_i - x_{n+1})}\prod_{\substack{j=1\\j\neq i}}^n \frac1{x_i - x_j}
- f(x_{n+1})\prod_{\substack{j=1}}^n \frac1{x_{n+1} - x_j} \\
=\,& f(x_0)\prod_{\substack{j=1}}^n \frac1{x_0 - x_j} + 
(x_0 - x_{n+1})\sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i)\prod_{\substack{j=0\\j\neq i}}^{n+1} \frac1{x_i - x_j}
- f(x_{n+1})\prod_{\substack{j=1}}^n \frac1{x_{n+1} - x_j} \\
=\,& (x_0 - x_{n+1}) \left( f(x_0)\prod_{\substack{j=1}}^{n+1} \frac1{x_0 - x_j} + 
\sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i)\prod_{\substack{j=0\\j\neq i}}^{n+1} \frac1{x_i - x_j}
+ f(x_{n+1})\prod_{\substack{j=0}}^n \frac1{x_{n+1} - x_j} \right) \\
=\,& (x_0 - x_{n+1}) \sum_{i=0}^{n+1} f(x_i)\prod_{\substack{j=0\\j\neq i}}^{n+1} \frac1{x_i - x_j} \\
=\,&(x_0 - x_{n+1}) \ell[x_0, \cdots, x_{n+1}].
\end{align}

Excuse the mess. The idea isn't too complex, it just takes a ton of space to write out in LaTeX. We just showed that $\ell$ satisfies the divided difference recursive formula
$$
\ell[x_0, \cdots, x_{n+1}] = \frac{\ell[x_0, \cdots, x_n] - \ell[x_1, \cdots, x_{n+1}]}{x_0 - x_{n+1}}.
$$
And since $\ell[x] = f[x] = f(x)$, it must be that $\ell[x_0, \cdots, x_n] = f[x_0, \cdots, x_n]$.

Now we can prove by induction that $q_n$ = $p_n$ for all $n$. For the base case, you can easily verify that $q_0 = p_0$. Now assume that $q_n = p_n$, and consider
$$
r(x) = q_n(x) + c \cdot (x - x_0)(x - x_1)\ldots(x - x_n),
$$
where $c$ is chosen so that $r(x_{n+1}) = f(x_{n+1})$. (Note that there is one and only one such value of $c$.) Clearly, $r$ is the unique $n+1$ degree polynomial which meets $f$ at $x_0, x_1, \cdots, x_{n+1}$. Thus $r = p_{n+1}$. But since $c$ is the leading coefficient of $r = p_{n+1}$, we have $c = \ell[x_0, \cdots x_{n+1}] = f[x_0, \cdots x_{n+1}]$. Thus
$$
p_{n+1}(x) = r(x) = q_n(x) + f[x_0, \cdots x_{n+1}] \cdot (x - x_0)(x - x_1)\ldots(x - x_n) = q_{n+1}(x).
$$
This completes the induction.